# How to show dateTime values on x-axis in Vega Chart with time interval of 5 minutes

Tags: timestamp, linechart, vega

I am plotting timestamp values on x-axis in Vega chart. Since the amount of data is huge, it shows tick labels with a gap of 24 hours (or 12 hours) based on tickCount value. Can anyone suggest me how to plot the tick labels with less time interval (For eg. 5 minutes). I tried to increase the range in *scales* attribute, but it seems to lag a lot to render on the Vega editor.

[Link of spec that I'm using in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

Also, can anyone tell if plotting labels with lesser time interval is the same thing as zooming in ? Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the number of tick labels by decreasing the distance with

```
"tickCount":  {"signal": "ceil(height/20)"}
```